# transition not applied with z-index

Tags: css, animation, sass, css-transitions, z-index

I've a footer depending on **tglinsetftrp**  the transition effect has to be done.Theirs a sidebar on which the footer toggles

```
 <footer className={"page-footer font-small blue  " + (this.props.dltheme? 'darkfooter':'lightfooter') + (this.props.tglinsetftrp?' ftInsetTransIn':' ftInsetOut')}>                    
            <div className="footer-copyright text-center py-3">© 2018 Copyright:                     
            </div>                    
        </footer>
```

> css

```
.ftInsetOut{
    margin-left:0px ;
    z-index: 8;
    position: relative;
    @include transition(all 0.9s ease);

 }
.ftInsetTransIn{
    margin-left: -250px;
    position: relative;
    @include transition(all 0.5s ease); 
 }
```

Here these footer transition effect is applied to inner div and not to footer.I did googled n tried the solutions not working.

z-index is applied to footer but then not the transition effect.

Can we do it by animation or zindex with transition will work out.
m building the sass way

Any help is apprecited.

Comment: bro you do not change z-index so how it can be animate ??

Comment: @kousheralampranto do i need to change to ** low value  z-index for ftinsetransIn**

Comment: @kousheralampranto applied zindex doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

```
  .ftInsetOut{
    left:0 ;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 32px;
    z-index: 8;
    position: relative;
    @include transition(all 0.9s ease);

}
.ftInsetTransIn{
    left: 250px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 32px;        
    position: relative;
    @include transition(all 0.5s ease); 
}
```